# Schedule PHP file to run

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, timer

Is there a way to run a PHP file automatically every hour(60min) or start the file you could say? 
I'm currently working on a file who's job is to bring information from a table every hour. This file needs to execute every hour. Is there any way to do this?
it is not a build-in facility. 
however it can be done by some external tools or using some other php code written for it and loaded on the server i've heard.

If someone consumes this knowledge it would be greatly appreciated!
Best regards.

Comment: Google for `php cron`

Comment: yes, cron is the way, PHP is a server-side, it runs when you render the page, or via a javascript, but it would need to be active in order to do what you ask

Comment: Create a cronjob or use windows task scheduler depending upon you are on Linux or Windows.

Comment: if you have using linux machine .Then you might have access of webmin .In the webmit click to the system and click on the system and then cron jobs .Then you can configure the cron job with the required intervals. and in command give the absolute path like cd /var/www/filefolder/; /usr/bin/php -q filetoexecute.php

Answer (score 1):

Try some thing like `PHP CRON`.

In `Linux`,

Open terminal

Execute command `crontab -e`

Eg:30 11 * * * /your/path/to/php /var/www/some/path/script.php

It will executes script.php at 11.30 am every day.

In that window,you can set up the time for running the file.(need to specify the absolute path of the file need to be run.)

Comment: I'm running this file on a remote server on www.one.com.

Comment: It doesn't look like your host supports cron at all judging by [this link on their facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/Onecom/posts/10151179357275930)

Comment: That line won't work, you are not calling `php` to run that script

Answer (score 0):

As I remember my situation on same problem, I have no access to cronjob, but I decide to update data just when someone of website visitor load page. I just wrote last update time to some tmp-file and every time check it like: if(lastupdatetime>=now()-60minutes){update}else{do nothing or some else with old files}

Answer (score 0):

You can set manual PHP Cron by adding some information in databse.

1) You create a database for cron and time when it runs.
2) Now create cron.php or whatever and include it in db connection file so whenever db connection runs, it will also run cron.php file
3) In cron file, keep checking database first. If last it run before 60 minutes and let the codes run and you can if/else for that.

It is very simple and you can find tutorials on youtube. A simple tutorial is here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S-UZsAk_UiE

Comment: I have no access to 3rd party apps.
Using a SQL server provided by one.com

Comment: So what is your problem? You don't need third party app to cron your site.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Linux: type `crontab -e` in a terminal.
This entry should work:

```
0    0-23 * * *    php -f /path/to/script.php
```

EDIT: You need some program or machine that acts like a **trigger** if you really want to save the data every hour. If it's right for you to do it when somebody open's a page, you could write a function in your php script, where you check if one hour is elapsed and then trigger a database backup.